# Pause and resume scheduled task

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I need to pause and resume a scheduled task.

I see many code examples to cancel() a task, but I would need then to resume/restart it also. I see suggestions doing this:

```
public void init(){
    scheduledTaskExecutor.getScheduledThreadPoolExecutor().setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
}
public void schedule(String id, Runnable task){
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task);
    runningTaskRegistry.put(id, task);
}

public void suspend(String id){
    ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = runningTaskRegistry.get(serviceName);
    if(scheduledFuture != null){
        scheduledFuture.cancel(false);
        try{
            scheduledFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | CancellationException e){
            // I do not want the currently running task finishing after this point
        }
    }
}
```

...and then I need to schedule again instead of restart.

Is that REALLY the best way to do this?

Comment: Generally, yes, re-scheduling your task is the best way to do it.  One hack that comes to mind is using a [single-thread executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor--), and passing it a task that waits until the pause condition is false.

Comment: Single-threaded executor is not an option here: I have dozens of long-running processes to run and some of them is quite long-running.

Comment: Old, question, but if the disabling option (distinct from the end option) is available when using Task Scheduler GUI, then why is it not supported in schtasks? You can even see the disabled task show up as disabled using schtasks /query. Seems like a competency deficiency over at Redmond to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer rescheduling over pausing and resuming. Not just because I don't know how to do this, but also because paused tasks probably won't release their threads. During this time, those executor threads block and do nothing even if there're other tasks waiting in the task queue.

To not lose intermediate results, you could put them in another queue which are picked up before new tasks are scheduled. You could also implement pausing and resuming based on that queue.

Comment: I fully agree that blocking an executor thread is not a good solution. I just thought that the executor itself can do this removing into a temporary list and then rescheduling... :-)
One more solution could be to create a Wrapper/Proxy around Runnable and handle pause and resume there: not by blocking the thread but by ignoring the original runnable when paused :-)
That would cause only minimal overhead with minimal boilerplate code.

Comment: @BTakacs I think it really depends on what your tasks are going to do and if you're able to reuse intermediate results. As mentioned before, I know no implementation that allows *efficient* pausable and resumable tasks, i.e. threads are not just being blocked. I'd suggest you try out [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to "park" tasks and pick them up again. Let me know if you want me to give you an example.